# OpenCV C++ - How can I replace the value of each pixel with the average value of the grayscale in a 3x3 neighborhood?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV (in C++) and image processing. I want, given a grayscale image to replace the value of each pixel computing the average value of the grayscale in a 3x3 neighborhood.

First of all I open the image

```
Mat img = imread(samples::findFile(argv[1]), IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

// Example of image
[4 3 9 1,
 2 9 8 0,
 3 5 2 1,
 7 5 8 3]
```

In order to get the average value of the 3x3 closest pixels of corners (top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right) I make a padding of the image: an 1x1x1x1 constant border

```
Mat imgPadding;
copyMakeBorder(img, imgPadding, 1,1,1,1, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0));

// Padding example
[0 0 0 0 0 0,
 0 4 3 9 1 0,
 0 2 9 8 0 0,
 0 3 5 2 1 0,
 0 7 5 8 3 0,
 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Now I've got some troubles with the output image. I have tried in various ways, but no way brings me to the solution. I tried this, using [mean() function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.9/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga191389f8a0e58180bb13a727782cd461) to get the average grayscale value of the i,j-th 3x3 matrix got with [Rect() method](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.9/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html#a5a41149f4b012b9f323b5913454375a1). The for loop starts from the first non-padding pixel and ends at the last non-padding pixel.

```
Mat imgAvg = Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, img.type());
// initialization of the output Mat object with same input size and type

for (int i = 1; i < imgAvg.rows; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j < imgAvg.cols; j++) 
        imgAvg.at<Scalar>(Point(j - 1, i - 1)) = mean(imgPadding(Rect(j - 1, i - 1, 3, 3)));
```

but I got this runtime error

```
main: malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
```

I tried also reducing randomly the range

```
for (int i = 1; i < imgAvg.rows - 35; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j < imgAvg.cols - 35; j++) 
        imgAvg.at<Scalar>(Point(j - 1, i - 1)) = mean(imgPadding(Rect(j - 1, i - 1, 3, 3)));
```

and I got this weird output: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYPUu.png)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Thank you all for the answers, I didn't know yet the `blur()` function.
In this way I import the image and simply call the blur function

```
Mat img = imread(samples::findFile(argv[1]), IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
Mat imgAvg = Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, img.type());

blur(img, imgAvg, Size(3, 3));
```

But since I'm still a beginner and I think the purpose of the exercise assigned to me was to write a "handmade" code, I tried also this working solution

```
for (int i = 1; i <= imgAvg.rows; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= imgAvg.cols; j++) 
        imgAvg.at<uint8_t>(Point(j - 1, i - 1)) = mean(imgPadding(Rect(j - 1, i - 1, 3, 3)))[0];
```

[Result of the algorithm (identical for both solutions)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcpnC.png)

Comment: This is what [`blur`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga8c45db9afe636703801b0b2e440fce37) does.

Comment: You are reading out of bounds, should be: `i < imgAvg.rows-1` and `j < imgAvg.cols-1`. You have image with depth == 1, one color component as grayscale, value is stored in `uint8_t` type. Because `cv::mean` returns Scalar, you should take its first element at 0 index, and assign it to uint8_t: `imgAvg.at<uint8_t>(..) = mean(...)[0];`.

Comment: @rafix07 this was the solution I was looking for. Besides the out of bounds error I didn't know which type to insert in the template ```imgAvg.at<>()```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply a smoothing filter to the image - the `blur` function in the `imgproc` module should accomplish what you need. A good example is in the documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dd3/tutorial_gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html

In this case, the arguments you need are the image (`img`), a destination image (`dst`), and kernel size (`ksize`), which is 3 in this case:

```
src = ...
Mat dst = Mat::zeros( src.size(), src.type() )
blur( src, dst, Size( 3, 3 ))
```

Smoothing manually will not be as performant, and is more prone to error.

Good luck!

Comment: It should be posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called "box filtering" in image processing. In OpenCV you do:

```
cv::blur(src_img, 
         dest_img, // same shape and type as src, cannot be src
         cv::Size(3, 3))  // use a kernel of size 3x3
```

The default padding is to reflect the border pixel, which won't skew the image statistics. See the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga8c45db9afe636703801b0b2e440fce37) if you prefer a different border mode.